# gensim.similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity get segmentation-fault

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, gensim

I want to get the similarity of one document to other documents. I use gensim. The program can run correctly, but after some steps it exits with Segmentation fault.

Below is my code:

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
docs = [['Looking', 'for', 'the', 'meanings', 'of', 'words'],
        ['phrases'],
        ['and', 'expressions'],
        ['We', 'provide', 'hundreds', 'of', 'thousands', 'of', 'definitions'],
        ['synonyms'],
        ['antonyms'],
        ['and', 'pronunciations', 'for', 'English', 'and', 'other', 'languages'],
        ['derived', 'from', 'our', 'language', 'research', 'and', 'expert', 'analysis'],
        ['We', 'also', 'offer', 'a', 'unique', 'set', 'of', 'examples', 'of', 'real', 'usage'],
        ['as', 'well', 'as', 'guides', 'to:']]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in docs]
nf=len(dictionary.dfs)
index = similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(corpus, num_features=nf)
phrases = [['This',
            'section',
            'gives',
            'guidelines',
            'on',
            'writing',
            'in',
            'everyday',
            'situations'],
           ['from',
            'applying',
            'for',
            'a',
            'job',
            'to',
            'composing',
            'letters',
            'of',
            'complaint',
            'or',
            'making',
            'an',
            'insurance',
            'claim'],
           ['There',
            'are',
            'plenty',
            'of',
            'sample',
            'documents',
            'to',
            'help',
            'you',
            'get',
            'it',
            'right',
            'every',
            'time'],
           ['create',
            'a',
            'good',
            'impression'],
           ['and',
            'increase',
            'the',
            'likelihood',
            'of',
            'achieving',
            'your',
            'desired',
            'outcome']]
phrase2word=[dictionary.doc2bow(text,allow_update=True) for text in phrases]
sims=index[phrase2word]
```

It can run normally until get sims, but it cannot get sims, and using `gdb` gets the following info:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007fffd881d809 in csr_tocsc (n_row=5, n_col=39,
>   Ap=0x4a4eb10, Aj=0x9fc6ec0, Ax=0x1be4a00, Bp=0xa15f6a0, Bi=0x9f3ee80,
>   Bx=0x9f85f60) at scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h:411 411
>   scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h: 没有那个文件或目录.

Comment: if i replace dictionary.doc2bow(text,allow_update=True) to  dictionary.doc2bow(text,allow_update=False) it can run correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have get the answer from  [github](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1883#issuecomment-364326041)

The main reason is that num_features should be same with the dictionary.dfs